# I got error java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:Excel

Tags: java, excel, oracle

Using Jdeveloper 12C, Oracle DB 12C, Windows 8.1 
this is my code to read Excel File to DB.

This is an Image for the code I

[link to the code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw2j1f9Dl5_MRUZfcXNfeXI4dVk/view?usp=sharing)

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream
    (new File("E:/Company Mails.xlsx"));
     XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);   
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);    
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();          
        DCBindingContainer bindings2 = (DCBindingContainer) 
        BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
        JUCtrlHierBinding obj = (JUCtrlHierBinding) 
        bindings2.findCtrlBinding("CompanyMails1");
        ViewObject vo = obj.getViewObject();            
        BindingContainer bindings = BindingContext.
        getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
        OperationBinding operationBinding = bindings.
        getOperationBinding("Commit");                            
                while (rowIterator.hasNext()){                        
                    Row row = rowIterator.next(); 
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                    oracle.jbo.Row r = vo.createRow();                        
                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()){
                        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                        r.setAttribute("No", row.getCell(0));
                        r.setAttribute("Mail", row.getCell(1));
                        r.setAttribute("Person", row.getCell(2));} }
                file.close(); operationBinding.execute();}
            catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); }
    return null;}
```

this is the message I get on the Jdev

```
<org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase> <UIXComponentBase> <getClientId> <INVALID_CALL_TO_GETCLIENTID>  <oracle.adf.controller> <Utils> <buildFacesMessage> <ADF: Adding the following JSF error message: For input string: "No">  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "No"     at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
```

"No" as A String is the head of first Column in Excel File 
this is a pic for the error I got after running the code.

[link to the error i got on the browser](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw2j1f9Dl5_McnZtMjFQQjYzdGM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: i think overloaded version of `public void setAttribute(int index,                   java.lang.Object value)` method is called so it is not able to convert **"No"** in to **integer index**.

Answer (score 0):

The `setAttribute()` method needs the index of the column. Not the column Header.
So you have to change to:

```
r.setAttribute(0, row.getCell(0));
```

Comment: setAttribute() here is for the column name, what i need to to bypass the first row in the sheet which contains the header.

Comment: this is to insert the value of cell 0 to a a column in Oracle DB

Comment: Can you also you the structure of your table?

Comment: No (Number) Mail(Varchar2) Person(Varchar2) excel is the same.

Comment: @MahmoudAbdelAzim Can you take a look in the server logfile if you find more informations?